# Base64 encoding of multiple files

Tags: xml, file, batch-file

I need to base64-encode all the files contained in one of my folders.

How can I do this?

Comment: Based on the way you've worded your question, it sounds like you already know how to encode a single file in base64 and you just need help performing an action on every single file in a folder. Is that accurate?

Comment: Nope, just a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%a in (*.xls *.xlsx ) do (
   certutil  -f -encode "%%a" "%%a.b64"
)
```

?

Comment: Thanks npocmaka! This will be in a batch file, right?

Comment: @JayeshG - yes.

Comment: In this case, where the files are created? I'm running the batch file in the folder itself and i don't see the encoded files in that folder.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `certutil -encode "%%a" "%%a.b64"`?

Comment: @SomethingDark - yes.THanks.

Comment: @JayeshG - what are the extensions of the files you want to convert?

Comment: .xls and .xlsx files.

Comment: @JayeshG - try now.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot, npocmaka!!